# Correct Bluetooth profile for audio + 4 custom messages

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-profile, iwrap

We are working with a Bluegiga's iWrap enabled Bluetooth controller from an Android application.

We are in constant communication with a BT programmers. Our application has to receive four custom events from the BT accessory and a two way audio (playback and listening).

We are now trying to figure out a Bluetooth profile that would allow us to complete an app communication.

Right now if we use SPP we are easily receiving custom messaged that BT accessories is sending as a byte stream. The problem is, when we use SPP, the A2DP profile disconnects, and we lose "easy" audio connection.

Is there, and if so, which one of the numerous BT profiles would allow us, as andoid developers to have audio connection to an BT chip + be able to process 4 different events (AT commands, whatever) from a device?

Comment: If you want 2 way audio , you need to use SCO(handfree profile) , use your own AT commands which can be send over HFP profile

Comment: @ashish, will I be able to process the AT commands from my application's code?